# Hiding ActionBar in Android 3.0

Tags: android, themes

I want to hide the title/action bar in my Android Application.  I have different themes for different Android Firmware.  This is in my manifest which references the theme.xml files...

```
android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"
```

First "theme.xml" --Works fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Any customizations for your app running on pre-3.0 devices here -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Second "theme.xml" --This is my problem.  The code has no errors, but when I run the application in an emulator running Android 3.1, the action bar is still at the top.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Any customizations for your app running on 3.0+ devices here -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Third "theme.xml" --Works fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Any customizations for your app running on 4.0+ devices here -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Do you have the second _theme.xml_ in the _values-v11_ folder? Also, I assume you mean you have tried `Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar` as there is no `Theme.Holo.Light.NoTitleBar`.

Comment: Yes I do have the theme.xml in the values-11 folder.  Sorry for the typo I meant to say "Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" - Edited question

Comment: And now that you have `Theme.Holo.Light` there, that works?

Comment: It turns out a simple clean project has fixed my initial problem.  But the action bar is still at the top with this code.  (question edited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Holo_Light_NoActionBar), you can see that `Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar` was really added in API 13. So I guess you can't do it this way. Try using `Theme.Holo.Light` and doing this to remove the action bar:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

If that alone doesn't work, also try adding `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>` as ianhanniballake states in his answer.

Comment: From the latest [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml), it looks like it also adds `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>`

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, I wonder, did you have to use the `windowNoTitle` feature from ianhanniballake's comment or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you second `theme.xml` is in the `values-v11` folder, then it will only be loaded on v11+ (i.e., Honeycomb+) devices and your third should be in the `values-v14` folder for ICS+ devices as per the [select a theme guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#SelectATheme).

Comment: Yes, my second theme.xml is in the values-v11 folder and the third is in the values-v14 folder.  But I still do not see why I cannot use "Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" when I have a theme for a lower api.

Comment: I assume this is a Lint warning (as they are the only warnings about minimum SDK level) - can you clean and rebuild your project and/or re-run Lint on the file?

Comment: Ok, rebuilding the project has gotten rid of the error but when I run the application in an emulator running Android 3.1, the action bar is still at the top?